# Direct link to Google Drive Image not working [in CodeSkulptor]

Tags: python, google-drive-api, codeskulptor

I have uploaded to google drive and dropbox(public folder) images that is not loading why is that when i access public url of google drive give as error saying (403. That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL /U7NFy4SAHqDw6I3-Yd11AG2fi5QaCiIsn62wqOJO0gPRO68G5yfGurFiVm75HezqRtmrwlE33lxRyTF6 from this server. (Client IP address: 103.21.166.13)

ACL Denied That’s all we know.)

This is my codeskulptor code.

```
import simplegui

message = "Welcome!"

# Handler for mouse click

image = simplegui.load_image('https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bworipp9D5BbQ0t1aVE2NDlsaXc/edit?usp=sharing')
# Handler to draw on canvas
def draw(canvas):
    canvas.draw_image(image, (596, 25), (1192, 50), (100, 100), (128, 128))
    print image.get_width();
    print image.get_height();
# Create a frame and assign callbacks to event handlers
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Home", 300, 200)

frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

# Start the frame animation
frame.start()
```

Comment: When I try the URL in your code, I get a 302 response redirecting me to https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bworipp9D5BbQ0t1aVE2NDlsaXc/edit?usp=sharing, which then downloads fine. (Of course, that's a web page, not an image, so it's not going to work in your code.) That's on the Google Drive side. What's the Dropbox URL you're trying to download?

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive does not make direct links readily available to uploaded files.
This can be circumvented by changing the URL from:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bworipp9D5BbQ0t1aVE2NDlsaXc/edit?usp=sharing

to:

> https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8w52Vdma1fVMDhiZmlieEJxQ28

You can see that this is based on the general template of the following URL where you simply insert your file id from the original link:

> https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=

*Source: Google forums.*

Comment: Seems like this link also works: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=